# Logging Error Spring boot Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, logging, gradle

I am getting the following error when i trying to user loggin in my application

```
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/home/dev/code/my_proj/build/libs/proj-core-0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:346)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:205)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
        at com.abc.def.Application.main(Application.java:22)
        ... 8 more
```

This is my logback.xml

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%.7thread] %level %logger{10}:%line %mdc%n %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>


    </appender>

    <logger name="com.abc" level="debug"
            additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This is my dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
        exclude module: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support'

    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy'
}
```

I am using them as below.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
@Service
public class MyService {
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyService.class.getName());
```

My application is not even starting
I tried google search but its very confusing as I am new to Gradle and logging. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two jars with an implementation of Logback and they are competing to be the active one, as expressed on the *Caused by* message which also suggest a solution: remove `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/home/dev/code/my_proj/build/libs/proj-core-0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext`

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/home/dev/code/my_proj/build/libs/proj-core-0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

If this error occurred in SpringBoot when you are trying to use log4j2 then
do these steps:

- Remove the jar from while packeging by adding this "excludeGroupIds log4j-slf4j-impl  /excludeGroupIds"
- Find out the which library is depends on "logback-classic" by using command "mvn dependecy:tree"
- Wherever you find it exclude it from the dependency.

This error occurred because logback override the log4j2 changes. SO if you want to use log4j2 then you have to remove logback library and dependencies.

Hope this will help someone.